# SOAP client for Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, saaj

I have faced up to building **SOAP** client for Android. I found out there is a **ksoap2** lib from some posts, for example. But there is **SAAJ** (**SOAP** with Attachments API for Java) as well.

My question is: is it possible to use it? Has anyone ever tried **SAAJ** for Android apps?

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If the WSDL for your target service is not that complicated you should check out [httpclient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/package-summary.html) bundled with Android core libraries.  It's trivial to use.  You can trap request/response through [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and then use them as base XML templates within your client.

Comment: Thank you for giving one more alternative! It can be considered either though i still want to know about SAAJ. It seems to be more convenient...

Comment: no problem. All I would suggest is to stick with core android core libraries wherever you can.  Good luck and let us know if you find more information on this one.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use SAAJ for android unfortunately. It relies on the javax.xml package, which android won't work with.